# AngularJS using the $compile service to add angular elements dynamically, added directives post link functions are executed incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a link to how directive link function executed in the correct order(not my article): 
[Correct Execution Order](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/)

Basically if you have nested directives like so:

```
<level-one>  
    <level-two>
        <level-three>

        </level-three>
    </level-two>
</level-one>
```

The execution order should look like this:

COMPILE PHASE

- levelOne:    compile function is called
- levelTwo:    compile function is called
- levelThree:  compile function is called

PRE-LINK PHASE

- levelOne:    pre link function is called
- levelTwo:    pre link function is called
- levelThree:  pre link function is called

POST-LINK PHASE

- levelThree:  post link function is called
- levelTwo:    post link function is called
- levelOne:    post link function is called

When using the $compile service to add directive dynamically to a view the post link functions are executed in reverse order. Where the parent directive's post link function is called before its children's post link function are called.

Here's a link to my plunker that demonstrates this: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/769dN6KFx1DUblstXFyg?p=preview)

You will notice in the console that the "label" directive post link function is being called after its "parent" directive is called.

NOTE: I had to add an extra "parent" directive to the DOM or it would fail and you would not be able to see the execution order.

Is this by design or this a bug in angular?